# Volumes by integration of a rotated solid - horizontally shifted parabola about y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume of the solid formed by revolving the region bounded by the graphs of

$y=\frac{1}{2}(x-2)^2$ and $y=2$ about the y-axis.

So far, I know the $y-$limits of integration are $y=0$ and $y=2$ and that the volume of the outer donut is $$\pi\int_0^2 \left(2+\sqrt{2y}\right)^2 dy$$ but there is still a hollow cone inside of which I do not know how to calculate the volume in such a way that I could use the washer method.

Answer (score 1):

Solving for $x$ in terms of $y$, we get $x=2\pm\sqrt{2y}$. For the $y$ in our range, the radius of cross-section of the "hole" at height $y$ is $2-\sqrt{2y}$. 
This is the inner radius of our washer. The outer radius is the $2+\sqrt{2y}$ of your post.

Thus our volume is
$$\pi\int_0^2 \left[(2+\sqrt{2y})^2-(2-\sqrt{2y})^2\right]\,dy.$$ 
It is useful to simplify the integrand before integrating. There is a whole lot of cancellation going on.

Alternately, we can use cylindrical shells. Often, for rotation about the $y$-axis of a region bounded by $y=f(x)$, that leads to simpler calculations. Not this time.
But for the sake of comparison, note that cylindrical shells lead to the integral
$$\int_0^4 (2\pi x)\left(2-\frac{1}{2}(x-2)^2\right)\,dx.$$

Comment: The "shell method" _is_ the more convenient one here because the "slices" of infinitesimal volume are always _parallel_ to the rotation axis, and the upper and lower bounds of the region are easier to describe as functions of $x$. The "slices" in the "disk/washer method" are always _perpendicular_ to the rotation axis; in this problem, the only complication is that the parabola function does not have a single inverse that describes the complete curve.

Comment: Thank you so so so much for the help!

Comment: You are welcome. I hope everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Because  $y = \frac{1}{2} (x-2)^2$ is not a one-to-one function, you do not get a single function back when you have to invert it in order to get the boundaries of your "washers". The inversion gives $x = 2 \pm  \sqrt{2y}$, so you have correctly found the "outer radius" to be  $x = 2 +  \sqrt{2y}$, which is a function representing the "upper half" of the "horizontal" parabola, as viewed from the y-axis.  The "lower half" of the parabola, $x = 2 -  \sqrt{2y}$ is the other function from the inversion; this will serve as the "inner radius" for your slices.

So your integral will be $\pi \int^{2}_{0} [2 +  \sqrt{2y}]^2  - [2 -  \sqrt{2y}]^2 dy$.  This actually simplifies a fair bit when you multiply out the binomials.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help :)